# first-child pseudo class applied to all elements instead of the first

Tags: html, css

I am having a main container and some child elements inside each of them, and I want to specifiy some different property on the first element of the class `hello`, but its applied to all the elements instead of only the first one

```css
.hello:first-child {
background: #ffaaff;
}

.hello {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="hello"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="hello"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="hello"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="hello"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Every element with the class hello is the first child of the div (with class container) that it is in.

Comment: @Quentin, how can I still do it to the first one, what is the solution for it?

Comment: There is no `first-of-class` in CSS. Use `.container:first-child>.hello` (which will only work if that first `div.container` has no previous siblings.

Answer (score 4):

In you case, you need to select the first container and then apply the background to `.hello`

```css
.hello{
  background: orange;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.container:first-child .hello{
  background: #ffaaff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="hello"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="hello"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="hello"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="hello"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this. I listed a few below so you can choose one to your liking.

The `>`-combinator is key in situations like this if you have a container wrapping your elements, as it selects only the elements inside the parent. This way it won't affect other elements in your page that might share the same classname.

```css
/* This will only partially work, as there could be more <div> elements in the parent container that contains all the .container-elements */

/*
.container:first-of-type>.hello {
  background: #ffaaff;
}*/



/* This works if there is a container wrapping all the .container-elements, but will also affect other elements with .container-class name. * is a universal selector*/
/*

* >.container:first-child >.hello {
  background: red;
}
*/

/* If you have access to the HTML, you can assign an ID to that specific .container-element */

/*
#color {
  background: limegreen;
}
*/

/* Selecting the .container-element you want to target directly, this could also affect other .container-elements other places in your code.*/

/*
.container:first-child .hello {
  background: yellow;
}
*/


/* If you have something that wraps around the .container-elements, you can use that container to select its first child and then that containers child .hello - this is the method I would use. This would not affect other .container-elements other places on your page. */

body>.container:first-child>.hello {
  background: green;
}

.hello {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="hello" id="color"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="hello"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="hello"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="hello"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```