# How to use :fist-child correctly?

Tags: html, css

I have a html structure and would like to set the **margin-top** for the **first div** to 0. That is for the div that is surrounded with asterisk.

I tried to use the following css code but it does not work as required:

```
div:first-child {
    margin-top:0 !important;
}
```

as well as

```
a>div:first-child {
    margin-top:0 !important;
}
```

as well as

```
.l-content-width.l-content-width--narrow.l-stack.l-stack--chicken{
     div:first-child {
        margin-top:0 !important;
    }
}
```

here is my html:

```
 <div class="l-content-width l-content-width--narrow l-stack l-stack--chicken}">
        <a href="https://something&lang=de" class="t-link-area" target="_blank">
            **<div class="l-stack t-link-area__link" data-products-links>**
                <strong class="t-condensed">something</strong>
                
        <i class="c-icon c-icon--ui-arrow-right c-icon--m t-link-area__icon">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="c-icon__svg c-icon__svg--ui-arrow-right">
                <use href="#ui-arrow-right"></use>
            </svg>
        </i>
    
            </div>
        </a>
    
        <a href="https://something&lang=de" class="t-link-area" target="_blank">
            <div class="l-stack t-link-area__link" data-products-links>
                <strong class="t-condensed">something</strong>
                
        <i class="c-icon c-icon--ui-arrow-right c-icon--m t-link-area__icon">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="c-icon__svg c-icon__svg--ui-arrow-right">
                <use href="#ui-arrow-right"></use>
            </svg>
        </i>
    
            </div>
        </a>
    
        <a href="https://something&lang=de" class="t-link-area" target="_blank">
            <div class="l-stack t-link-area__link" data-products-links>
                <strong class="t-condensed">something</strong>
                
        <i class="c-icon c-icon--ui-arrow-right c-icon--m t-link-area__icon">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="c-icon__svg c-icon__svg--ui-arrow-right">
                <use href="#ui-arrow-right"></use>
            </svg>
        </i>
    
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
```

I am able to correctly solve this using JS/TypeScript but was wondering if there is a more elegant way to do it in pure CSS?

```
this.productsLinks = config.element.querySelector<HTMLSelectElement>('[data-products-links]');
if (this.productsLinks.classList.contains('l-stack')) {
       this.productsLinks.classList.remove('l-stack');
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot showing the current state of the page, and where the margin issue exists? I get the feeling that you may want to apply the margin: 0 to the a:first-child, but that's just a guess.

Comment: @j08691 I think it doesn't since it will apply to every first div inside a tag

Comment: That is correct @Cédric the first two apply to every first div inside a tag.

Comment: @Cédric Yup, I misunderstood the question. Something like `.l-content-width.l-content-width--narrow.l-stack.l-stack--chicken > a:first-child > div` should work however

Comment: I managed to get it to work @Cédric with the CSS code I wrote as a solution using the [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72182278/first-child-pseudo-class-applied-to-all-elements-instead-of-the-first) you've pointed me to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the divs in the code you have provided are first children (including possibly the very first one since at minimum it will be within a body element).

It is the anchor element that is the first child so you need to select that,  then this snippet selects the first direct child of the anchor element (rather than any child) as well:

```
.t-link-area:first-child > div.t-link-area__link:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @a-haworth for your solution. I managed to write the one below that also worked.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Cédric for pointing me in the right direction:

```
a:first-child div{
  margin-top: 0!important;
}
```